# Exclude babel polyfills for standard libraries

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

While bundling our TS project into es5 using babel and webpack, we see polyfills for standard string methods like

`String.replace`, `String.match`, `String.split`

```
$ Added following core-js polyfill:
  es.array.join { "ie":"11" }

$ Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.string.replace { "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ie":"11", "ios":"12", "safari":"12.1", "samsung":"9.2" }
  es.string.split { "edge":"17", "ie":"11" }
```

As per compatibility charts of MDN & other trusted compat tables, these methods are fully supported by all these platforms. But why would babel add polyfills for them remains a question to us.

Is there a way to disable polyfills of these standard methods via babel config? Below is our babel configuration, Hint us if we are missing something.

```
const presets = [
  [
    '@babel/env', // Using babel preset-env
    {
      debug: true, // Disabling debug output in console
      targets: {
        browsers: ['> 1%', 'not dead', 'not ie < 8'], // Spit code for all browsers with usage > 1% and not dead.
      },
      useBuiltIns: 'usage', // Use polyfills for runtime feature support
      corejs: 3, // Use core-js 3 Polyfills.
    },
  ],
];

const plugins = [
  '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', // Use Babel helpers to prevent code bloating with helpers
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```